# How to escape Path from Parameter for use in ADO task VSTest@2

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml, vstest

I am using a ADO Task(VSTest@2) for my build pipeline(in Yaml) 
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vstest-v2?view=azure-pipelines

My test libraries are having this path on the build agent:
D:\a\1\s\Target\Release\net472\ABC.DEF.GH.IK.Tests.dll

If I use this configs, **my tests are found and run**:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\Release\net472\*Test*.dll
     !**\obj\**
    platform: '${{ Parameters.BuildPlatform }}'
    configuration: '${{ Parameters.BuildConfiguration }}'
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
  timeoutInMinutes: 10
  continueOnError: true
  condition: eq(${{ Parameters.skipTests }}, false)
```

the above config will print this on my ADO task:
`Source filter: **\*Tests.dll,!**\*TestAdapter*.dll,!**\obj\**`

However, I want to fetch these paths for testAssemblyVer2 from parameters of the Yaml file. From here:

```
- name: TestFilePaths
  type: object
  default:
    - '**\*Tests.dll'
    - '!**\*TestAdapter*.dll'
    - '!**\obj\**'
```

If I use

```
  - task: VSTest@2
    displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
    inputs:
      testAssemblyVer2: |
        ${{ join( '\n', Parameters.TestFilePaths) }}
```

it will print this when I run the pipeline and **won't find any test**:

```
Source filter: **\*Tests.dll\n!**\*TestAdapter*.dll\n!**\obj\**
##[warning]No test sources found matching the given filter '**\*Tests.dll\n!**\*TestAdapter*.dll\n!**\obj\**'
```

I have also tried the following combination as well, but that did not help:

```
- task: VSTest@2
    displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
    inputs:
      testAssemblyVer2: |
        ${{ join( ',', Parameters.TestFilePaths) }}
```

escaped the paths in params as:

```
- name: TestFilePaths
  type: object
  default:
    - '**\\\\*Tests.dll'
    - '!**\\\\*TestAdapter*.dll'
    - '!**\\\\obj\\\\**'
```

Please let me know how can I make this to work? I want to use the paths from the params and use it in the ADO task.

Comment: Any reason why you're not defining the `TestFilePaths` as a string ?

Comment: Yes, this is a template which the client yaml can call. The client will send the multiple FilePaths in separate lines.

Comment: But then the parent yaml can still pass multilines string. IT does not have to be converted as an array